# Definition of category and natural transformations

Tags: category-theory

The book that I'am reading mentions the definition of a category as follows.

A category is a collection of abjects $\{X,Y, \ldots \}$ such that for two objects X, Y we have a set $\text{Mor}(X,Y)$ and for three objects $X, Y, Z$ a mapping (composition law),
$$ \text{Mor}(X,Y) \times \text{Mor}(Y,Z) \rightarrow \text{Mor}(X,Z)$$
satisfying the following axioms:

- Two sets $\text{Mor}(X,Y)$ and $\text{Mor}(X',Y')$ are disjoint unless $X=X'$ and $Y=Y'$, in which case they are equal.
- Each $\text{Mor}(X,X)$ has an element $id_X$.
- The composition law is associative.

Then a bit further in the text they define the natural transformation, which are the morphism of the category formed by the functors. If $\lambda, \mu$ are two functors from $\mathcal{U}$ to $\mathcal{U}'$ (say covariant), then a natural transformation $t:\lambda \rightarrow \mu$ consists of a collection of morphisms
$$ t_X : \lambda(X) \rightarrow \mu(X)$$
as $X$ ranges over $\mathcal{U}$, which makes the diagram commutative for every $f: X\rightarrow Y$, it is,
$$ \mu(f) \circ t_X = t_Y \circ \lambda(f).$$

My question is how one can show that this category indeed does satisfy the first point in the definition? (By this category I mean the category formed by the functors and where the morphisms are the natural transformations)

**My attempt:**
Consider that the two sets $\text{Mor}(\lambda,\mu)$ and $\text{Mor}(\lambda',\mu')$ are not disjoint. Then I would like to show that $\lambda=\lambda'$ and $\mu=\mu'$. Due to the consideration is it possible to take $t$ in the section of $\text{Mor}(\lambda,\mu)$ and $\text{Mor}(\lambda',\mu')$. Take an arbitrary set $X\in\mathcal{U}$ then,
$$ t_X \in \text{Mor}(\lambda(X),\mu(X)) \\ t_X \in \text{Mor}(\lambda'(X),\mu'(X)) $$

Due to the first point there follows that $\lambda(X) = \lambda'(X)$ and $\mu(X) = \mu'(X)$. And since $X$ was arbitrary this will be the case for every $X\in\mathcal{U}$.

It is at this point that I got stuck, could someone please help me further? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the name of the book? (Also, it appears to have odd notational choices, and, what appears to me, unfortunate definitional choices.)

Comment: The book that I am reading is "Introduction to Differentiable Manifolds" by Serge Lang. It is not like category theory is a fundamental topic of this book, however it was shortly mentioned in the introduction. Could you provide me with a book or text where they introduce it on a "sane" way like you mentioned on Alex Provost his post?

Comment: The typical approach is to define source and target maps from morphisms to objects which will automatically force the homsets to be disjoint. This is the approach taken in "Categories for the Working Mathematician" and Awodey's "Category Theory" and most other introductions to category theory I've seen. A rarer but arguably better approach is to work in a logic such as [FOLDS](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/FOLDS) or most dependent type theories where these sorts of questions would simply be un-askable, where there is no well-formed equality relation between morphisms of different homsets.

Answer (score 3):

You can't really prove that the actual collections of morphisms that constitute a natural transformation between two functors are distinct, because it's not always the case.

For example, if $\mathcal{U'}$ is the category $\mathbf{Vect}_{\Bbb R}$ of real vector spaces, then for any functor $\mu:\mathcal{U}\to \mathbf{Vect}_{\Bbb R}$ and any $a\in \mathbb{R}$, you have a natural transformation $\mu\Rightarrow \mu$ defined by $t_X:\mu(X)\to \mu(X):v\mapsto av$. This is a natural transformation regardless of how $\mu$ is defined on arrows, so if $\mu'$ is a functor $\mathbf{U}\to \mathbf{Vect}_{\Bbb R}$ that agrees with $\mu$ on objects (i.e. such that $\mu(X)=\mu'(X)$ for all $X$ of $\mathcal{U}$) but not on morphisms, then the same collection $(t_X:\mu'(X)\to \mu'(X))$ would also constitute a natural transformation $\mu'\Rightarrow \mu'$.

In fact, a part of this example works for any category $\mathcal{U'}$ : the identity natural transformation $\mu\Rightarrow \mu$ is always given by the collection of identities
$$(id_{\mu_X}:\mu(X)\to \mu(X))_{X\in Ob (\mathcal{U})},$$
so it does not depend on how $\mu$ is defined for morphisms. Thus if $\mu'$ is as above, we have again that the identity $id_\mu$ is technically equal to the identity $id_{\mu'}$. The example above is basically the same case, except that since the category $\mathbf{Vect_\Bbb{R}}$ is enriched over itself, all multiples of the counterexample are also counterexamples.

---

The point is, as Alex Provost said in his answer, that we consider that every natural transformation $t:\lambda\Rightarrow \mu$ has an assigned domain $\lambda$ and codomain $\mu$, and that these are part of the definition of $t$. This is similar to the case of functions between sets : if you define a function $f:A\to B$ as a set $\Gamma \subset A\times B$ such that for every $a\in A$ there is a unique pair $(a,b)\in \Gamma$, and then two functions with different codomain can technically be seen as the same set $\Gamma$. But if you consider that $A$ and $B$ are part of the definition of $f$, this is not possible.

Comment: Concretely, one often states that the arrows of $\mathbf{Set}$ are *triples* $(A,f,B)$ where $f[A]\subseteq B$. So $f : A \to B$ means the triple $(A,f,B)$. Of course, this is but one possible implementation. (And of course, you don't actually need $A$ as that's already implied by $f$.)

Comment: @DerekElkins, yes, that's what I meant by "consider that $A$ and $B$ are part of the definition of $f$".

Comment: @ArnaudD. My intent was simply to elaborate on the point and illustrate what "consider[ing] $A$ and $B$ as part of the definition" means.

Comment: Another counter-example is to use functors from the arrow category, $\mathbf{2}$, into any (not too trivial) category, $\mathcal{C}$, with a terminal object. Given two functors $F, G : \mathbf{2}\to\mathcal{C}$ corresponding to two arrows of $\mathcal{C}$ between the same objects, The (unique) natural transformation $F\to\Delta 1$, to the constantly terminal object functor, will be the same as $G\to\Delta 1$.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of this post is to point out what I believe is a mistake in the question and in the accepted answer.

The OP defines a category as

> a collection of objects $\{X,Y, \ldots \}$ such that for two objects X, Y we have a **set** [emphasis added] $\text{Mor}(X,Y)$ ...

Later the OP writes

> ... the natural transformations, which are the morphism of the **category** [emphasis added] formed by the functors ...

The statement that the collection of morphisms between two functors is a set is made repeatedly throughout the thread.

Let's show that it is not so:

Let $\mathcal C$ be the unique category whose objects are the sets and whose morphisms are defined as follows: $\hom_{\mathcal C}(X,Y)=\varnothing$ if $X\neq Y$ and $\hom_{\mathcal C}(X,X)=\{\text{id}_X\}$.

Let $\mathcal C'$ be the usual category of sets.

Let $F$ be the unique functor from $\mathcal C$ to $\mathcal C'$ such that $F(X)=X$ for all $X$.

If there was a set $S$ whose elements are the endomorphisms of $F$, then for each set $X$ we would have a surjection from $S$ onto the set of endomaps of $X$. This is clearly impossible.

**Edit.** Let us define a category as given by a collection of objects, and, for each pair of objects, a *collection* of morphisms satisfying the usual axioms, *without* the disjointness condition. Then it is easy to see that each category is canonically isomorphic to a category with disjoint Hom-collections.

Comment: You are in fact correct that the above answers do not really answer the question, therefore I have unmarked this question as answered. The reason that I did so is because I figured from the above answers that the definition that was given there is simply not a good starting point to category theory. Can I conclude that this definition badly defines the concept of a category?

Comment: I think you're right. I haven't checked by I believe you quoted the book accurately. If so the problem is with the book. The simplest solution would be to define a category as consisting of a collection of objects (as you do), and, for each pair of objects, a *collection* of morphisms satisfying the usual axioms. A perhaps cleaner way would be to use Grothendieck universes, but most people prefer not to do so...

Comment: ... At any rate, if one finds satisfactory to consider that the objects form a collection, I don't see why the morphisms between two given objects would not be allowed to form a collection as well. If you chose the simple solution, then it would suffice to change some occurrences of "set" to "collection".

Comment: @Dylan_VM - I think most people do *not* require the disjointness condition. See for instance these two recent books written by experts, and freely and legally available: [Leinster](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf) and [Riehl](http://www.math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/context.pdf). - Sorry I forgot to use the @ sign in my previous comments

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard Leinster uses a FOLDS-like approach but points out: "If you believe it makes sense to form the intersection of an arbitrary pair of abstract sets, you should add to the definition of category the condition that $\mathscr{A}(A,B)\cap\mathscr{A}(A',B')=\emptyset$ unless $A=A'$ and $B=B'$." In FOLDS, such an intersection is meaningless. Riehl uses a source-target approach which implies disjointness.

Comment: @DerekElkins - I was wrong about Leinster (I missed the remark you quote). Thanks for the correction! You write "Riehl uses a source-target approach which implies disjointness". Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard Riehl states "Each morphism has specified domain and codomain objects". Presumably intending a pair of class functions or some other suitable notion of "large function", and explicitly intending set functions in the small case. It immediately follows that $f:X\to Y$ and $f:X'\to Y'$ implies $X=X'$ and $Y=Y'$.

Comment: You're right again! I realize that I hadn't payed enough attention to your other comments on this thread.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much to prove here. By definition, a natural transformation $t:\lambda \to \mu$ goes from a specified functor $\lambda$ to another specified functor $\mu$. That is, the "source-target" data $(\lambda,\mu)$ is uniquely determined by $t$. A fortiori, a single natural transformation cannot have two distinct sources or targets, which implies disjointness of the morphism sets.

Comment: While requiring a source and target function is the normal (and sane...) way of handling this issue, and will automatically lead to different hom-sets being disjoint, that doesn't appear to be how this book is axiomatizing things.

Comment: Alex: Are you claiming that the morphisms from a functor to another form a *set*?