# Are the sets of morphisms of a category always disjoint?

Tags: category-theory

Suppose we have the category of Sets. Suppose we have $f \in Hom(A, B).$ Now consider $Hom(C, D)$ where $A \subset C, B \subset D.$ We can construct a function $g \in Hom(C, D)$ such that $g|_A = f.$ My question is whether or not $g$ and $f$ are actually different functions. I know that $Hom(A, B)$ and $Hom(C, D)$ should be disjoint but it seems like we can create these similar functions where they behave the same in a set of morphisms.

Comment: See also this question about the case of categories of functors : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2331297/definition-of-category-and-natural-transformations

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps unsatisfactorially, this depends on how you choose to define categories. With regard to your question, there are two possible approaches:

- **Approach A.** A category $\mathcal{C}$ consists of a set $\mathcal{C}_0$ of objects and a set $\mathcal{C}_1$ of morphisms, together with functions $\mathrm{dom},\mathrm{cod} : \mathcal{C}_1 \to \mathcal{C}_0$ assigning to each morphism a *domain* and *codomain* (+ other data and axioms).
- **Approach B.** A category $\mathcal{C}$ consists of a set $\mathcal{C}_0$ of objects and, for each pair of objects $A,B$, a set $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(A,B)$ of morphisms from $A$ to $B$ (+ other data and axioms).

These approaches appear to be equivalent at first sight. To go from Approach A to Approach B, take $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(A,B)$ to be the subset of $\mathcal{C}_1$ consisting of all those $f \in \mathcal{C}_1$ such that $\mathrm{dom}(f) = A$ and $\mathrm{cod}(f)=B$. However, going from Approach B to Approach A isn't necessarily possible, since if the hom sets are not disjoint, then $\mathrm{dom}$ and $\mathrm{cod}$ might not be well-defined.

So to answer your question, the answer is 'yes' if you take Approach A, and 'not necessarily' if you take Approach B.

In Approach A, the domain and codomain of a morphism are intrinsic to the morphism itself: if you say that $f$ is a morphism, then it has a specified domain and codomain. In Approach B, morphisms are specified relative to a domain and codomain, so a particular $f$ might be a morphism $A \to B$ and a morphism $C \to D$.

This manifests itself in set theoretic (ZFC) foundations, in that there are two commonplace ways of defining a function:

- A function is a triple $(A,B,f)$, where $A$ and $B$ are sets and $f \subseteq A \times B$ is a set such that $\forall a \in A,\, \exists ! b \in B,\, (a,b) \in f$
- Given sets $A$ and $B$, a function from $A$ to $B$ is a set $f \subseteq A \times B$ such that $\forall a \in A,\, \exists ! b \in B,\, (a,b) \in f$.

The first of these aligns with Approach A, since the domain and codomain are part of the data defining the function. Thus, functions with different domains and/or codomains cannot be equal.

The second of these aligns with Approach B, since we don't define 'function'; we only define 'function from $A$ to $B$'. And, indeed, the set $f = \{ (0, 0) \}$ is a function $\{ 0 \} \to \{ 0 \}$ and a function $\{ 0 \} \to \mathbb{R}$ (and so on). So in this case, the same set can define many different morphisms.

Which approach you take is a matter of taste. Personally, I prefer Approach A, for a few reasons, two of which are: (1) definitions relative to domains and codomains (e.g. totality and surjectivity) are properties of morphisms, not morphisms relative to particular domains and codomains; and (2) I do a lot of work with [internal categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+category) and that definition is easier to internalise.

---

***Footnote:*** I should add that I'm consciously ignoring issues of size here (i.e. large vs. locally small vs. small categories) because I don't think they're relevant to the question.

Comment: Amazing explanation! Thank you very much!

Comment: I would note that in "Approach B styles", it's quite possible that the very question of whether $\text{Hom}(A,B)$ is disjoint from $\text{Hom}(C,D)$ is non-sensical, i.e. there is no well-formed formula that corresponds to this proposition. In other words, in (some of) those approaches, you can't even *ask* if two hom-sets are disjoint.

Comment: It appears to me that the language usually used for _talking_ about category theory implicitly assumes approach A. For example people speak freely about a "coequalizer of $f$ and $g$" without bothering to specify explicitly which objects are involved.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I wouldn't say that. I agree that people are often not explicit about the objects involved, but the information needed for "Approach B" is usually inferable, in fact, *mechanically* inferable. The process is similar to type inference in programming languages or implicit argument inference in proof assistants such as Agda or Coq, all of which take an "Approach B" view toward functions.