# What if domains and codomains in categories were not unique?

Tags: soft-question, category-theory, definition

I were updating my knowledge of category theory, which were generally obtained from the books treating categories not as their primary subject. So, I decided to read books on the subject.

By comparing these texts I discovered that there are several different approaches regarding definition of category:

$\textrm{(CD.a)}$ For category $\mathcal{C}$  with objects $A,B,C,D \in \mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{C}}$ its hom-classes are $\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{C}}(A,B)$ and $\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{C}}(C,D)$ are disjoint whenever $A \neq C$ or $B \neq D$.

$\textrm{(CD.b)}$ Each hom-class $\mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{C}}(A,B)$ consists of triples $(A,B,f)$ with only last item $f$ bearing new intrinsic information.

Note that $\textrm{(CD.b)} \Rightarrow \textrm{(CD.a)}$. And it seems that the role of this assertion is to define $\mathrm{dom}$ and $\mathrm{codom}$ as viable maps from  class of all the morphisms of $\mathcal{C}$ to the $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{C}}$. For example, In case $\textrm(CD.a)$ one can define
$$
\mathrm{dom}  (A,B,f) = A \kern 1pc \mathrm{codom}(A,B,f) = B.
$$

In my fairly limited practice I always selected objects first and morphisms later as elements of corresponding hom-sets, so I rarely addressed $\mathrm{dom}$ and $\mathrm{codom}$ as maps directly. This raised some question for me:

> Can  property $\mathrm{CD}$ (in every form)  be painlessly dropped from definition of category?
>
> Is it useful to have $\mathrm{dom}$ and $\mathrm{codom}$ to be well-defined as maps to develop any useful theorems and tools in category theory? Or фre they just common parts of mathematical lingo?
>
> Have anyone studied objects which are like categories but have $\mathrm{CD}$ dropped from the definition?

If property $\mathrm(CD)$ is dropped then $\mathrm{dom} $ and $\mathrm{codom}$ can be defined at least for small categories as sets:

$$ \mathrm{dom}(f) = \{ A \in \mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{C}} : \exists B \in \mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{C}}  : f \in \mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{C}}(A,B)   \}, $$

$$ \mathrm{codom}(f) = \{ A \in \mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{C}} : \exists B \in \mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{C}}  : f \in \mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{C}}(B,A)   \}. $$

I can present examples where this notion is not redundant:

(1)

Consider category $\mathsf{TOP}$ with topological spaces as objects and continuous maps as morphisms. Then $\mathbb{R}$ has multiple corresponding objects in this category, say $(\mathbb{R},a)$ and $(\mathbb{R},b)$ being real numbers with normal ans discrete topologies $a$ and $b$ respectively. And Let $\mathbf{1} = \{1\}$ be a one-point set. Then the constant map  $1 : \mathbb{R} \to \{1\}$ belongs both to $\mathcal{M}_{\mathsf{TOP}}((\mathbb{R},a),\mathbf{1})$ and $\mathcal{M}_{\mathsf{TOP}}((\mathbb{R},b),\mathbf{1})$.

(2)

Consider category $\mathsf{SET}$ with objects are sets and morphisms are maps defined along with ZF; I. e. $f : A \to B$  is a subset of $f \subset A \times B $ with the property that $$\forall a \in A \; . \; \exists b \in B : (a,b) \in f \quad \& \quad \forall b,c \in B \; . \; (a,b),(a,c) \in f \Rightarrow a = b.$$

Let $A,B$ are sets and $\emptyset \neq S \subsetneq B$. Then, if $f \in \mathcal{M}_{\mathsf{SET}}(A,S)$ it must also  be present in $\mathcal{M}_{\mathsf{SET}}(A,B)$. So $f$ has nonsingular codomain.

Comment: We can consider the constant map $\mathbb R\to\{1\}$ as $Gu=Gv:\mathbb R\to\{1\}$ in category $\mathbf{Set}$ where $G$ denotes the forgetful functor $\mathbf{Top}\to\mathbf{Set}$ and $u$ is the arrow $(\mathbb R,a)\to\mathbf1$ and $v$ is the arrow $(\mathbb R,b)\to\mathbf1$ both in $\mathbf{Top}$, and distinct. So your example does not convince me that the notion is not redundant.

Comment: @drhab , of course,  but this depends on the definition of redundant.

Comment: @drhab ; additional example was added. It still weak as it relies on underlying  set theoretic formalism.

Comment: If you forget about codomains in $\mathsf{SET}$, all morphisms are now epimorphisms, i.e., all maps of sets are surjective now. You probably don't want that. You also need a notion of codomain to define things like cokernels in abelian categories etc.

Comment: Here is a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651464/is-it-necessary-for-the-homsets-to-be-disjoint-in-a-category).

Comment: @Christoph , thanks for the comment. I think, that in this case property of being epimorphism or cokernels can be defined with respect to a pair of objects $(A,B)$ such that $f : A \to B$. For example, $f$ is an epimorphism of $A$ and $S$, if $S = \mathrm{Im} 
 \; f$, but $f$ is not an epimorphism of $A$ and $B$. simmilirarly, you can define cokernel of $f$ with respect to domain $A$ and codomain $B$.

Comment: @drhab , thanks, this is the same question indeed.

Comment: Here's another related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2462477/19542 (I remembered answering something like this a while ago)

Comment: @CliveNewstead ; Thanks this is indeed related.

Comment: A relevant fact is that if $S$ is a set, also viewed as a discrete category, then there is an equivalence $\mathbf{Set}^S \equiv \mathbf{Set}/S$. In the case of considering the definition of a small category, this relates the notion of an arbitrary function $\hom : \mathbf{Ob}(C) \times \mathbf{Ob}(C) \to \mathbf{Set}$ (i.e. where the images aren't required to be disjoint) to the notion of a family $\mathbf{Ar}(C) \xrightarrow{(\mathrm{dom}, \mathrm{codom})} \mathbf{Ob}(C) \times \mathbf{Ob}(C)$. The two approaches are indistinguishable if you respect equivalences!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define the notion of category in any of the language of First-Order Logic with Dependent Sorts (FOLDS) or dependent FOL (DFOL) or as a generalized algebraic theory or in a dependent type theory in such a way that there are no $\mathsf{dom}$/$\mathsf{codom}$ operations and asking whether $\mathsf{Hom}(A,B)$ is or is not disjoint from $\mathsf{Hom}(C,D)$ is a  meaningless question. In particular, in these formalizations there is no notion of equality of objects. (There is still a notion of equality of arrows, but we can only ask about it for arrows that are declared to be of the same hom-sort/hom-type.)

This isn't just a neat trick. FOLDS, in particular, was designed to achieve this. Or rather, FOLDS was designed to be a formal language in which one could do category theory and the [principle of equivalence](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence) (well, the principle of isomorphism) would automatically hold. That is, every property you can state in FOLDS, say, is isomorphism invariant: if the property holds for one object, it holds for all isomorphic objects. Equality of objects is clearly not isomorphism invariant, and so it is not a predicate you can formulate in FOLDS.

To answer your question, yes we can drop CD and the notion of $\mathsf{dom}$ and $\mathsf{codom}$ operations entirely, but we need to restrict ourselves to a language where they are meaningless. But restricting ourselves to such a language is a good thing because properties outside this language do not satisfy the principle of isomorphism (and such properties are often referred to as "evil"). Since [strict categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/strict+category) appear to be a thing, I assume they are sometimes useful/necessary. (Normal) FOL and set theory don't really provide a way to formalize the notion of category without including this extraneous structure either explicitly or implicitly, hence the existence of FOLDS and co. In practice, we just *informally* restrict ourselves (for the most part) to isomorphism invariant properties, so the fact that we are allowed in usual formalizations to test equality of objects and that $\mathsf{dom}$/$\mathsf{codom}$ exist are usually ignored. This is similar to how we simply don't ask questions like is $\mathbb Q\subseteq \arcsin(1)$ even though they are technically legitimate questions in a set-theoretic context.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to get. IMHO it is natural to see $\mathrm{Hom}(A,B)$ as types. However, I don't know if this approach works well for establishing basic categories of topology and algebra which are generally presented in set-theoretic context.