# If the objects of a category form a proper class, do the arrows necessarily form a proper class too?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

In some categories, like $\text{Set}$ or $\text{Group}$, the objects are "constructed" out of sets (or are sets, possibly with additional structure). In order to avoid paradoxes, the collection of objects is therefore a proper class✱.

If the class of objects is proper, is it possible for the collection of arrows to still be a set?

A not-convincing argument against it is that each object gets an identity arrow therefore there are "too many" arrows to be a set. I don't trust intuitions about size with things as big as $\text{Set}$ though.

A not-convincing argument that it's plausible is that arrows are opaque and I, the category-maker, get to freely pick the labels for the arrows, the definition of the composition relation, and the source and destination for each of the arrow-labels. How do I show that I can't come up with a set of labels big enough to label all of my arrows?

---

✱ I don't know whether it makes sense to start with a "possibly-proper class of all sets satisfying some predicate" and then inspect the class in some way to see if it's a proper class or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to have a category whose objects are a proper class and yet the arrows form set, in fact they can form a singleton. Consider for example the category $\mathcal{C}$ whose objects is the class of all sets. We let $\hom(a,b) = \emptyset$ unless $a = b$ in which case we let $\hom(a,a) = \{ * \}$ for some fixed set $*$. We furthermore define composition via $* \circ * := *$. This is a category with a proper class of objects and only one arrow.

---

Let me add the following: If you are only interested in categories from the point of view as a category theorist (and not as a set theorist), you can, without loss of generality, assume that for any given category $\mathcal{C}$ we have $a \neq b \implies \mathrm{id}_{a} \neq \mathrm{id}_{b}$ and here's why:

Given $\mathcal{C}$ construct a new category $\mathcal{D}$ with the same objects as $\mathcal{C}$ and such that, for $a,b \in \mathrm{ob}(\mathcal{D})$
$$
\hom_{\mathcal{D}}(a,b) := \{ (a,b,f) \mid f \in \hom_{\mathcal{C}}(a,b) \}
$$
and
$$
(b,c,f) \circ_{\mathcal{D}} (a,b,g) := (a,c, f \circ_{\mathcal{C}} g).
$$
$\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are equivalent from the point of view of category theory and moreover they preserve all sorts of nice set theoretical properties (e.g. $a \mapsto \mathrm{id}^{\mathcal{C}}_{a}$ is definable if and only if $a \mapsto \mathrm{id}^{\mathcal{D}}_{a}$ is definable).

And $\mathcal{D}$ satisfies that $a \neq b \implies \mathrm{id}^{\mathcal{D}}_{a} \neq \mathrm{id}^{\mathcal{D}}_{a}$.

Comment: ... so in order to "label" my arrows and define a category, I only need to come up with local/per-object-pair labels?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet I'm not sure what you are asking. In this example with have $\mathrm{id}_{a} = *$ for all objects $a$, so we cannot read of $a$ from $\mathrm{id}_{a}$.

Comment: I'm asking why $\mathrm{id}_a = *$ is allowed at all ... or why it defines a category. I was under the impression that arrows with different source and destination objects cannot be equal ... and that that's a law that you need to satisfy to be a category. Relaxing that restriction so that only arrows in the same homset need to be distinct is cool, but I don't know why it's okay to do.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet My definition of category is the one found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_(mathematics)) and it allows for the possiblity that arrows with different domains and codomains are still the same object. Granted, this isn't the case in any natural example that I can think of, but the question was whether the arrows *necessarily* form a proper class. The above shows that, while this usually is the case, this isn't necessarily true.

Comment: It is a convention for some authors that no distinct arrows can be equal.

Comment: While technically correct, such a category really goes against the spirit of category theory (more precisely, of structuralism), and this property (of the union of all Hom-s being a set) is not preserved by equivalence, so it is not really a category theoretical property (unlike, say, the notion of a locally small category).

Comment: @tomasz That's why I added the clarifying section at the end of my previous answer.

Comment: @StefanMesken: I know, I just think that saying that you can assume that without loss of generality is an understatement. Not only can you assume that, it doesn't really make sense not to assume that.

Comment: @StefanMesken Another problem that can occur is that most definitions of categories mention the existence of domain and codomain functions from the set of arrows to the set of objects. In this example, those functions cannot exist.

Comment: @StefanMesken "Each morphism f has a source object a and a target object b where a and b are in ob(C). We write f: a → b, and we say "f is a morphism from a to b"." from wiki. If you assume there is only one morphism, then there must be only one object. The question was about the collection of all the morphisms, i.e. the disjoint union of all the homsets, even if the set is always the same the union will be bigger.

Comment: Not only this definition goes against the spirit of category theory; it also goes against the usual definition of category: if "we cannot read of $a$ from $\text{id}_a$" the function that sends an object to its identity is not injective. All references I can think of, however, take the $C(a,b)$ disjoint sets.

Comment: @Fosco Even if $C(a,b)$ was constantly the same singleton the collection of all morphisms will have a partial operation that will distinguish between objects. The union as a set theoretic concept is really an illdefined concept

Comment: While I agree that in the usual definition, one wants the set of morphisms between different objects to be distinct, there are relatively natural situations where it does not hold if we don't specifically require it as Stefan does in his answer; see for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2331297/definition-of-category-and-natural-transformations).

Answer (score 6):

They have to form a proper class as well.

For every object there is an identity arrow, so there must be more (or, in a discrete category, equally many) arrows than objects.

Comment: That makes sense. How do I show that an injection coming from a proper class always goes to a proper class and can't go to a set?

Comment: It may be that we have a different definition of "category". But I disagree with this answer, since it needn't be that $a \neq b \implies \mathrm{id}_{a} \neq  \mathrm{id}_{b}$ (though this is true in many/most/all natural examples).

Comment: @StefanMesken there are different views on this, agreed. I have seen the requirement you‘re referencing being added to the definition of a category, though I am not sure where.

Comment: @LukasKofler I looked up his definition ([here](http://angg.twu.net/MINICATS/awodey__category_theory.pdf)) and my example fits. So you may want to add the assumption that $a \neq b \implies \mathrm{id}_{a} \neq \mathrm{id}_{b}$ to be valid. (Beyond that, depending on your background theory, there still might be a slight issue. Namely that $a \mapsto \mathrm{id}_{a}$ also should be definable. Otherwise there are really pathological counterexamples that most mathematicians would probably be very annoyed with...)

Comment: @StefanMesken We can eliminate objects all together and identify $A$ with $id_A$. Do you have an example category where $a\ne b$ but $id_a=id_b$?

Comment: @John See below.

Comment: @StefanMesken Nice. That is simple but I have never seen that.

Comment: @JohnDouma I've edited my answer to reflect the fact that the example I was giving (and any other such example) really shouldn't concern any category theorist.

Comment: @StefanMesken I see that. I had already upvoted your answer so if you notice that you haven't received another it doesn't mean I ignored you. As I said, I had never seen or thought about that example so I learned something new today. Thank you.